# How do I set a field value in entry_submission_ready hook handler?

Tags: channel, hook

It seems that changing the values of the $data argument variable doesn't change anything.

Is there a way to change the value of some channel fields inside the `entry_submission_ready` hook?

Comment: I think you might need to get a reference to $data from the function argument instead of the value. http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/210027/#1047804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After tinkering around, I found out that the way to do it is to set these values inside the method

```
$this->EE->api_channel_entries->data['my_field_id'] = 'my_field_value';
```